# Composing IHandler<T>

Tags: kotlin

Here is a composable `IHandler<T>` implementation. Any ideas on how to make it shorter and get rid of exception being thrown?

```
interface Handler<T> {
    fun handle(e: T)

    operator fun <TOther> plus(other: Handler<TOther>): Handler<Any> =
        Composite(this, other)

    private class Composite<T1, T2>(
        private val left: Handler<T1>, 
        private val right: Handler<T2>) : Handler<Any> {
        override fun handle(e: Any) {
            try { left.handle(e as T1) } catch(ex: ClassCastException) { }
            try { right.handle(e as T2) } catch(ex: ClassCastException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Smoke test looks like this:

```
val h = A() + B()
h.handle("33") // prints 'String: 33'
h.handle(33)   // prints 'Int: 33'
```

where:

```
class A : Handler<String> {
    override fun handle(e: String) = Debug.println("String", e.toString())
}

class B : Handler<Int> {
    override fun handle(e: Int) = Debug.println("Int", e.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't want the jvm to keep track of types for you by catching exceptions, you can do it yourself. I imagine its much faster than waiting for ClassCastExceptions but I didn't benchmark at all:

```
interface Handler {
    fun handle(e: Any)
    fun handlesType(t: Class<*>): Boolean
    
    operator fun plus(other: Handler): Handler =
        Composite(this, other)

    private class Composite(
        private val left: Handler,
        private val right: Handler
    ) : Handler {
        override fun handle(e: Any) {
            if (left.handlesType(e::class.java)) {
                left.handle(e)
            } else if (right.handlesType(e::class.java)) {
                right.handle(e)
            }
        }

        override fun handlesType(t: Class<*>) = 
            left.handlesType(t) || right.handlesType(t)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> handler(crossinline fn: (T) -> Unit) = (object : Handler {
    override fun handle(e: Any) { fn(e as T) }
    override fun handlesType(t: Class<*>) = T::class.java.isAssignableFrom(t)
})

val A = handler<String> { println("String: $it") }
val B = handler<Int> { println("Int: $it") }

val h = A + B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `inline fun` and `reified` it's actually possible to check if a value is of a type parameter before using it.

Now, I had to refactor this a bit because of some constraints:

- Check for `a is T` can only be done if `T` is `reified`
- Only inline function can have reified type parameters
- Virtual functions (e.g. interface methods) cannot be inline

So for me it was a bit of a puzzle to see how it could be done, but it could be done using something like this:

```
class Handler<T>(val function: (T) -> Unit) {
    inline operator fun <reified TOther> plus(other: Handler<TOther>): Handler<Any> = Handler {
        if (it is TOther) other.function(it)
        else this.function(it as T)
    }
}
```

Even if this is not the end result that you end up with, maybe it can help you explore future possibilities.